# how apache web server works

Tags: apache, web, webserver

Hi I just finished setting up my new apache web server from my laptop running windows 7. I created the server using apache, then port forwarded my laptops ip (port 80), and finally got myself a free domain using dot.tk. Ive added a few files and done some basic html stuff, and it is successfully up running and accessible to everyone through the domain. But i have a question. Lets say someone was to download files from the site. Is my local network's bandwidth consumed? If anyone can explain how this works that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, of course. How else would data get from the server to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data will run through all segments connecting the client (your end user) to the host (your hosted web server).

So if they need to get to your house where your laptop is to get to the web server, then your house's network connection's bandwidth will be used.

If you hosted it remotely on some shared server site like Amazon instead, then the bandwidth of remote clients accessing your server never uses your home connection's resources, it only uses the resources between their computer and Amazon.